# How to use scipy to optimize the position of n points?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I have a fitness function that takes in n points (where n is a positive integer greater than or equal to two) and outputs some arbitrary value. My goal is to maximize (or minimize) the output.

Now, I need to find an optimal or semi-optimal configuration of these points. I thought this might be an interesting problem to treat as a genetic algorithm where each point is a "trait" if you treat the set of n points as the animal.

I have been researching how to implement genetic algorithms and I find the part about which of these configurations of points should die particularily confusing. Should I just kill all configurations that are less fit than the original? Should I weight them so that they are less fit than the original configuration? Or simply increase the probability that will die off. Any example code would help greatly as this is my first time implementing a genetic algortihm so any help would be appreciated.

I am using python for this project by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to me like a straight forward case for [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

If you function is differentiable (i.e. if you can define the Jacobian and/or Hessian matrices) I would recommend using a gradient-based method since they converge faster. Also it sounds like you have an [unconstrained](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#unconstrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize) minimization problem unless you have constraints on valid values of each point (or some other constraints).

So basically if you have your objective function

```
def fitness(points):
    # calculates fitness value
```

Then you can do something like

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x0 = [] # fill with your initial guesses
new_points = minimize(fitness, x0, method='Nelder-Mead')  # or whatever algorithm
```

Then `new_points` will be a list of the optimized points

For completeness, the full signature of `minimize` is

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
```

You can see that the two arguments following `method` are `jac` and `hess` which is where you may pass functions that can calculate the Jacobian and Hessian of your objective function, respectively. As I mentioned in the comments, if you are unable to calculate these (due to not having an equation describing your objective function or the objective function being mathematically non-differentiable) you can use gradient-free algorithms to perform the optimization.

Comment: Well, put quite simply I have no way of knowing whether the function is differentiable. My fitness "function" is actually the output of a complex physics simulation in my case. As such, I have no way knowing it is differentiable since it relies on so many variables. What approach would you recommend for non-differentiable function?

Comment: You should read the documentation for each algorithm, pay specific attention to if it is described as "gradient-based" or "gradient-free", you'll need the latter. For example [Nelder-Mead](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead) is a gradient-free method, and [BFGS](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#broyden-fletcher-goldfarb-shanno-algorithm-method-bfgs) is gradient-based, but can approximate the gradient using finite difference for you.